# How to pass in package.json array to grunt.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, gruntjs

is there a way to pass in an array to grunt.js from the package.json file? I've tried a few different ways and none of them seem to work. I currently have:

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

     // Project configuration.
     grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: '<json:package.json>',

    lint: {
      files: '<%= pkg.lint.join(", ") %>'
    }

    // Default task 'lint qunit concat min'
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'lint');
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "lint": [   
              "grunt.js",
              "test.js"
          ]
}
```

The only solution that I have been able to find is to pass in a specific index of the array; e.g. <%= pkg.lint[0] %>. 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try `<%= pkg.lint %>` instead? The lint task seems to accept an array, not a comma-separated list of files...

Comment: Yep, I've tried that as well. What is strange is that I can pass in an index to the array, such as pkg.lint[0] and it will lint that specific file.

Comment: As a quick debug method, try to change the last line to `grunt.registerTask('default', 'lint', function() {console.log(grunt.config('lint'))});` and see what gets output in the console...

Comment: I've also tried creating a helper in grunt.js, but it accepts all of it's parameters as strings...

Comment: What gets logged if you put the code I suggested above?

Comment: Of course @DmitryPashkevich is the right way, you can also use dot expression: grunt.config('pkg.version') etc.... return a JS object (such as Array, String ...)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since gruntjs in run in node you can access the package.json like:

```
var package = require('./package.json'),
    property = package.property[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the `<%= … %>` syntax (variable interpolation in [Underscore's template system](http://underscorejs.org/#template)) can only output strings, not arrays/objects.

Try this instead:

```
lint: {
    files: '<config:pkg.lint>'
}
```

I found this syntax in Grunt's [jQuery init task](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/tasks/init/jquery/root/grunt.js#L33).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I tried that, but I get <WARN> Unable to read "<json:package.json>" file (Error code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue. </WARN> when attempting that.

Comment: This is really weird, and you don't get this error if you remove the line with `<config:pkg.lint>`? The error seems to happen when the file is not found...

Answer (score 1):

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  lint: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json').lint,
});
```