# Declare multiple files in grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm new to Grunt so maybe this is an easy question, but I'm really at a loss with this...

I'm tying to declare all my files in "package.json" and inside grunt just import them.
Something like this:

```
// package.json
{
    "config": {
        "files": {
            "css": ["../assets/css/main.scss", "../assets/css/plugins.scss"]
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.5",
        "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.8.1"
    }
}
// grunt.js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            dev: {
                options: { style: 'compressed', noCache: true },
                files: { '../assets/min/min.css': '<%= pkg.config.files.css %>' }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass:dev']);
};
```

I says the source files are empty. But if I declare only one file it works just fine.

While if I declare them directly inside "grunt.js" works...

```
// grunt.js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            dev: {
                options: { style: 'compressed', noCache: true },
                files: { '../assets/min/min.css': ["../assets/css/main.scss", "../assets/css/plugins.scss"] }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass:dev']);
};
```

Can someone tell me how to make the first one work?

Thanks :)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think you can store your own properties in package.json - It's just a config file used by node to manage dependencies.   Why not just store the files in a separate object at the top of your gruntfile?

Comment: I've also tried that, and it works if I do this "css_files: ['main.scss', 'plugins.scss']," but I want to make a little function to concatenate paths to filenames something like this "css_files: function(){ return ['main.scss', 'plugins.scss']; },"

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the JSON file. It's really just a valid JS object without methods, so it knows how to handles strings, arrays, etc.

Comment: Looking at the [grunt templating guide](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates) it seems right what you are doing....

Comment: Instead of using package.json to list all of your sass files and then importing them one by one in grunt, i'd recommend having one sass file, `main.scss`, and importing your sass from there only. This way, you're managing the sass imports in one place and it should be more maintainable.

Comment: I've also remembered that workaround, I'm just trying to see if it's my mistake and why doesn't it work :)

Comment: Or, use wildcards: `../assets/css/**/*.scss`

Comment: The wildcards create two files instead of one

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by sticking `pkg.config.files.css` into the template, it's probably stringifying it. Try just passing in the variable directly:

```
// Wrong
'<%= pkg.config.files.css %>'

// Right
pkg.config.files.css
```

This way, Grunt will just pass in the array as you're expecting it to.

EDIT:

If this doesn't work, [here's an alternative way to access package.json.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408535/how-to-pass-in-package-json-array-to-grunt-js) While the above is valid JS, it may not be valid with Grunt because if `grunt.file.readJSON` runs asynchronously, it will be `undefined` until it finishes, which would be after grunt already initialized the config object. Thus, grunt goes back and inserts the data when it's available.

Comment: If I do that, grunt sais pkg it's not defined

Comment: Are you running the Grunt task from the same directory as `package.json`?

Comment: Yes, both os them are in root/grunt/

Comment: See edit above. That should solve/explain the problem.